# Using uv_close instead of uv_async_send for single use uv_async callbacks?

Tags: c, asynchronous, libuv

My understanding is that the proper use of `uv_async` for a single use is the following:

1. Allocate the `uv_async_t` handle;
2. call `uv_async_init` on the allocated handle;
3. call `uv_async_send` to schedule the callback;
4. unregister the handle using `uv_close`;
5. delete the `uv_async_t` handle in the close callback;

For example:

```
    uv_async_t *handle = (uv_async_t*)malloc(sizeof(uv_async_t));
    uv_async_init(&uvLoop, handle, [](uv_async_t *handle) { 
        // My async callback here
        uv_close((uv_handle_t*)handle, [](uv_handle_t* handle) {
            free(handle);
        });
    });
    uv_async_send(&asyncCb->uvAsync);
```

From what I gather, `uv_close` is called asynchronously in the uvLoop.  Therefore, I am tempted to do the following to avoid queueing two callbacks in the event loop:

```
    uv_async_t *handle = (uv_async_t*)malloc(sizeof(uv_async_t));
    uv_async_init(&uvLoop, handle, nullptr);
    uv_close((uv_handle_t*)handle, [](uv_handle_t* handle) {
        // My async callback here
        free(handle);
    });
```

Is anyone else doing this, and is it considered safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it you are tying to achieve?  Do you need to use multiple threads?  If so, that won't work since `uv_close` is not thread-safe.

If all you want is to schedule a callback in the future within the loop, check `uv_idle_t`. You could also use a queue and start / stop the handle as needed, instead of creating and destroying then.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the answer I needed.

While `uv_async_send` is thread safe, I did not realize `uv_close` is not. The second version of the code where I rely on `uv_close`'s callback is thus not thread safe and is not a valid substitute for the first version of the code.  In my tests, it was probably working out of pure luck waiting to explode in production.